# Render component in primefaces by value

Tags: primefaces

I want to hide this `Inputext`, but when I click on **true **it appears.
the code is bellow :

```
<div class="ui-sm-12 ui-md-4 ui-lg-5">
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="inptRME" value="#{bean.value}"
                        unselectable="true">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="true" itemValue="true" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="false" itemValue="false" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </div>
```

// this is what i wanna to hide and apears by true value

```
 <div class="ui-sm-12 ui-md-4 ui-lg-5" >
                    <p:inputText id="inptRES" value="#{bean.value2}"/>
                </div>
```

thank's all

[image]

Comment: Learn about ajax and the jsf 'render' attribute. Effectively your question is (in a more generic formulation) _"How do I conditionally  show/hide components"_

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you it work,but can i use another composant instead oh h:panelGroup ?

Comment: Sure... try...!